# ImportError: cannot import name 'DjangoDash' from 'django_plotly_dash'

Tags: python, django, python-import, plotly-dash

I'm attempting to follow the django-plotly-dash tutorial https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple_use.html but when using the code directly from this page:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample')   # replaces dash.Dash

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='dropdown-color',
        options=[{'label': c, 'value': c.lower()} for c in ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']],
        value='red'
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-color'),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='dropdown-size',
        options=[{'label': i,
                  'value': j} for i, j in [('L','large'), ('M','medium'), ('S','small')]],
        value='medium'
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-size')

])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-color', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown-color', 'value')])
def callback_color(dropdown_value):
    return "The selected color is %s." % dropdown_value

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-size', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown-color', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown-size', 'value')])
def callback_size(dropdown_color, dropdown_size):
    return "The chosen T-shirt is a %s %s one." %(dropdown_size,
                                                  dropdown_color)
```

and trying to run the server, I get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DjangoDash' from 'django_plotly_dash'
```

Is this deprecated and they haven't updated the tutorial or some other reason?

Comment: have you done proper installation and configuration...??

Comment: I did "pip install django-plotly-dash", do I need to do something else?

Comment: Please check the installation documentation [here](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#):

Comment: Do you have a file of your own named `django_plotly_dash.py`?